# Moving sprite to touch location no longer works after background has scrolled

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Im looking to get some help with my ios game. Its a simple game where i use a tilemap that scrolls vertically. I move my sprite by touching different locations and the spriteappears there. However i  have recently implemented scrolling from down to up and after a few seconds of my scrolling. my sprite no longer goes to the touched location but insteads sticks to the bottom of the screen.

this is a print of my NSLog

```
2014-05-01 17:44:06.628 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 359.500000
2014-05-01 17:44:06.629 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 301.000000
2014-05-01 17:44:10.794 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 396.500000
2014-05-01 17:44:10.794 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 288.500000

2014-05-01 17:44:14.427 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 401.500000
2014-05-01 17:44:14.428 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 261.000000

2014-05-01 17:44:16.811 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 397.000000
2014-05-01 17:44:16.812 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 256.500000

2014-05-01 17:44:18.880 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 399.000000
2014-05-01 17:44:18.881 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 245.000000

2014-05-01 17:44:21.444 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 405.000000
2014-05-01 17:44:21.445 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 297.500000

2014-05-01 17:44:23.544 Toygame[3735:a0b] X location: 405.000000
2014-05-01 17:44:23.544 Toygame[3735:a0b] Y Location: 289.500000
```

It doesnt seem to go above 300 Y no matter how high on the screen i click on the screen as it keeps scrolling up, my sprite just appears at the bottom

Thanks for any help offered

### touch code

```
 (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
  SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location]; 



    if (teleports>0 & actPower==1) { 
      _player.position=location;
      NSLog(@"X location: %f", location.x);
      NSLog(@"Y Location: %f",location.y);
      teleports--;
      actPower=0;
    }

 }

- (void)moveBg
{
  if (_gameState!=PCGameStateStartingLevel)
  {
  [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bg" usingBlock:
   ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
     SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
   //  CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-BG_POINTS_PER_SEC, 0.0);
     CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake( 0.0,-BG_POINTS_PER_SEC);
     CGPoint amtToMove =     CGPointMultiplyScalar(bgVelocity, _dt);
    bg.position = CGPointAdd(bg.position, amtToMove);


   }];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jennifer. Please post the code related to scrolling and also the code related to your sprite moving to the touched location.

Comment: @sangony done, and the tilemap is the child of that bg. (cause i couldnt figure out how to scrolll the tilemap)

Comment: @Jennifer you could try looking at the method convertPoint:toNode:

Comment: @Ilario Doesnt that say to put my SKNode at wherever i touch? I was thinking that self is probably assigned to the current dimension of the current view being shown. so when that "Scrolls away" it cant get the locations past that.

Comment: I actually solved it. my touch location was being placed in the wrong node *slaps self*